# Keep Firefox suggestions pane open when middle-clicking on suggestions

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, mouse-click

When you type into the address bar of Firefox, it opens a pane containing suggestions:

[image: Firefox's suggestions pane, showing a variety of Stack Overflow related links]

Upon middle clicking on any of these suggestions, it opens the suggestion in a new tab, then switches to that tab, also removing what I'd typed into the address bar.

A GIF speaks louder than words here:

[image: gif]

What I'd like to happen is the default for Google Chrome, which is where the suggestions pane *doesn't* close upon middle-clicking a suggestion, meaning that I can middle-click to open many tabs from the pane:

[image: gif]

How can I emulate Chrome's pane middle-click behaviour in Firefox?

Comment: @fixer1234 A great little Windows program called ShareX

Comment: I... don't think this is possible. This isn't configurable.

Comment: I haven't been using Firefox much since the switch to Quantum (not a big fan of not having any of my awesome addons work any more) so I hadn't noticed this yet, but I feel this [should be reported to Mozilla in a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is that unfortunately this is *not possible* in Firefox.

There are however some other distributions of Firefox such as [WaterFox](https://waterfoxproject.org/en-US/), [PaleMoon](http://www.palemoon.org/) and a few others. Some are tailored towards privacy and others towards added functionality and optimisation. Have a read [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/108608/6-alternative-browsers-based-on-mozilla-firefox/) to see what the alternatives are. You may have better luck using a different browser but you *cannot* do what you're trying to do using Firefox itself.

Comment: Unfortunately I might have to accept that this is the case. Thanks for your answer though

Comment: Have you tried the Firefox add-on called 'Tab Mix Plus' as a final resort?

Comment: It's apparently not compatible with my version of Firefox.

Comment: I read that with Quantum it is not. But potentially an earlier version? If it solves your problem it might be worth downgrading maybe.